# line break symbols of pandas dataframe at pycharm interactive console

Tags: pandas, pycharm

[image: pandas dataframe at pycharm interactive console]

I tried below before print pandas dataframe at pycharm interactive console.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
```

But as you can see above, I got an unexpected result.

The weird thing is, a week ago, there was horizontal scrollbar with no line break symbols. I failed to find the option related to it at pycharm. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found. Don't check 'Wrap on typing' at Setting > Editor > Code Style > Default Options.